# How can i get one table's value from a another table of Database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, orm

I'm completely new to Laravel. 
Can someone please guide me on how to set up a relationship between two model `BorrowersRequest` and `Cars`?

I have done it on Request Status which is also a foreign key of `BorrowersRequest` and it's totally working. Now I'm thinking why it isn't working with the `Cars`.

**model**

```
class BorrowerRequest extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function requestStatus() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\RequestStatus');
    }

    public function requestedCar() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Car');
    }
}
```

this is in my **borrowershistory** Page. The request status works perfectly fine.

```
<tr>
                        <td><p class="text-muted"><small>Car to be Rented:</small></td>
                        <td><h6>{{ $borrower_request->requestedCar->car_name }}</h6></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p class="text-muted"><small>Date of Return:</small></td>
                        <td><h6>{{ $borrower_request->return_date }}</h6></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p class="text-muted"><small>Request Status:</small></td>
                        <td><h6><em>{{ $borrower_request->requestStatus->request_status }}</em> 
 </h6></td>
                    </tr>
```

here's my **Controller**

```
public function viewBorrowManager()
{
    $borrower_requests = BorrowerRequest::all();
    $request_statuses = RequestStatus::all();
    return view('/borrowmanager', [
        'borrower_requests' => $borrower_requests,
        'request_statuses' => $request_statuses
    ]);
}
```

and my in **Migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('borrower_requests', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('car_id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('borrowers_name', 50);
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->bigInteger('contact_number');
        $table->date('return_date');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('request_status_id')->default(0);
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('car_id')->references('id')->on('cars');
        $table->foreign('request_status_id')->references('id')->on('request_statuses');

    });
}
```

Comment: Is there some errors ?

Comment: hi yes i has sorry i forgot to include. it says Trying to get property 'car_name' of non-object (View: C:\Users\Ethel\Documents\zuitte\CSP2\resources\views\borrowershistory.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want `car_name` column value from `Cars` model or `cars` table associated with `borrower_request`,you need to approach like this

```
$borrower_request->requestedCar()->find($borrower_request->car_id)->car_name
```

**Short explanation**

Here **`$borrower_request->requestedCar()`** this return **`App\Car`** instance,so avobe code of line is equivalent to

```
use App\Car;
$car = Car::find($id);
$car->car_name
```

And `$borrower_request` has a column of `car_id` which is belongs to the `App\Car` model.

Comment: Hi, thanks you for your response. i tried it and it works perfectly. and also i found out that i when i make  public function requestedCar() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Car', 'car_id);
    } it also works fine . thank you

Answer (score 2):

The car for some borrower_request is not exists. You can check it in view:

```
<td><p class="text-muted"><small>Car to be Rented:</small></td>
                        <td><h6>{{ $borrower_request->requestedCar ? $borrower_request->requestedCar->car_name : '' }}</h6></td>
```

Or you can add query for getting only borrower request with cars:

```
$borrower_requests = BorrowerRequest::whereHas('requestedCar')->get();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response :) the car exists in my databases, i mean i already saved some record on my database. when i put only $borrower_request->car_id it shows only the id of the car. i try using what you said {{ $borrower_request->requestedCar ? $borrower_request->requestedCar->car_name : '' }} but it shows only what i input in the ' '